# Map inside a map in Java

Tags: java

I want to put map in value field of map:

```
Map<String,String> innermap = new HashMap<String, String>();
Map<String ,Map<String,String>> map = new HashMap<String ,Map<String,String>>();

map.put("AAA", innermap.put("ab", "a , b") );
```

This gives me below error:

```
The method put(String, Map<String,String>) in the type Map<String,Map<String,String>> is not applicable for the arguments (String, String)
```

is that even possible ? if yes how to use map inside a map or any other technology that substitute this structure ?

Comment: Yes it's possible, and works just like any other object inside a `Map`.

Comment: I tried that but it gives this error... I will update my question

Comment: What do you expect the result of `innermap.put("ab", "a, b")` to be? (What does the documentation tell you it will be?) And why are you trying to combine the two calls into a single statement? Just separate it into `innermap.put("ab", "a, b");` and `map.put("AAA", innermap);`

Comment: Your problem is that you are trying to do everything in one line. First do `innermap.put("ab", "a , b")` and then do `map.put("AAA", innermap)`. You cannot combine those 2 into one single line.

Comment: @JonSkeet.. I got your point...if I use " map.put("AAA", innermap); ".. then suppose if I have 2 keys in innermap, and I want 2nd key... will that be extracted... I will get All key value pairs at that particular key.... I think JSON will help do that ?

Comment: @TheCuriousGuy: I'm afraid I don't follow your comment at all - in particular I have no idea where JSON would come into this. If you want a map that can store multiple values per key, that's an entirely different question.

Comment: Sorry to confuse you .. I used JSON just for structure reference and data extraction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can do it.  As already shown explained one might do it like this.

```
Map<String,String> innerMap = new HashMap<>();
Map<String ,Map<String,String>> map = new HashMap<>();
innerMap.put("ab", "a, b");
map.put("AAA", innerMap);
```

But as of Java 8 you can create the map as a value if it doesn't exist which is then returned using `computeIfAbsent`  If the value (i.e. map) doesn't exist for the key, it is added and then returned.  Otherwise, the value (i.e. map) is simply returned for the given key.

```
Map<String,Map<String,String> map = new HashMap<>();
map.computeIfAbsent("BBB", v->new HashMap<>()).put("r","s");
map.entrySet().forEach(System.out::println);
map.computeIfAbsent("BBB", v->new HashMap<>()).put("t","v");
map.entrySet().forEach(System.out::println);
```

prints

```
BBB={r=s}
BBB={r=s, t=v}
```

Answer (score 0):

The put method on a Map does not return the map you're putting to... you need to switch your code round slightly:

```
Map<String,String> innermap = new HashMap<String, String>();
Map<String ,Map<String,String>> map = new HashMap<String ,Map<String,String>>();
innermap.put("ab", "a , b")
map.put("AAA", innermap);
```

Answer (score 0):

It will work like this

```
    Map<String,String> innermap = new HashMap<String, String>();
    Map<String ,Map<String,String>> map = new HashMap<String ,Map<String,String>>();
    innermap.put("ab", "a , b");
    map.put("AAA",  innermap);
```

innermap.put("ab", "a , b") returns String(previous value associated with the key "ab" or null if this key is not found in map ) and that's why when you do

```
map.put("AAA", innermap.put("ab", "a , b") );
```

you get compile time error **The method put(String, Map<String,String>) in the type Map<String,Map<String,String>> is not applicable for the arguments (String, String)**
because the return type of innermap.put("ab", "a , b") is String

Answer (score 0):

`innermap.put("ab", "a , b")` will return the type of your value --> in your case is String.

In code source java : `public interface Map<K,V>`  fonction `V put(K key, V value);`

```
 * @return the previous value associated with <tt>key</tt>, or
 *         <tt>null</tt> if there was no mapping for <tt>key</tt>.
 *         (A <tt>null</tt> return can also indicate that the map
 *         previously associated <tt>null</tt> with <tt>key</tt>,
 *         if the implementation supports <tt>null</tt> values.)
```

when you put all in line, java will try to evaluate `innermap.put("ab", "a , b")` in your parameter first then you will get the result null with type String, after that java will evaluate `map.put("AAA", yourStringResult);`  That's why it shows you error in log :

you can't put `(String,String)` to a map of `Map<String,Map<String,String>>`

You should do this :

```
Map<String,String> innermap = new HashMap<String, String>();
Map<String ,Map<String,String>> map = new HashMap<String ,Map<String,String>>();
innermap.put("ab", "a , b")

map.put("AAA", innermap );
```